# how to bind data to a div in asp.net repeater?

Tags: asp.net, repeater

Since I have a field, which contain html content, in dataset returned from database. I want to sue a div to display the html content by using

```
div.innerHtml=...
```

I can find div control in Repeater1_ItemDataBound event but don't know how to bind that field to the control. That field is called 'actualContent'. I think write

```
div.innerHtml=<%=actualContent%> won't work in backend
```

Then how to bind that field? Thank you in advance.

Comment: How did you specify from what datasource this field comes from?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add runat="server" to the div, and put your content in between the tagsm like this:

**ASPX**

Literal method:

```
<div ID="div1" runat="server">
    <%#Eval("ActualContent")%>
</div>
```

DIV method:

```
<div ID="div1">
    <asp:Literal ID="Literal1" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("ActualContent")%>' />
</asp:Panel>
```

**Code behind**

Literal method:

```
string literalValue = ((Literal)e.Item.FindControl("Literal1")).Text;
```

DIV method:

```
string divValue = ((HtmlGenericControl)e.Item.FindControl("div1")).InnerHtml;
```

Comment: The actualContent fetching from database is in html format, do you think it will automaticly displayed in that format if I put the content in frontend as you suggested?

Comment: Assuming that the content is stored as HTML, I believe it should.

Comment: Thank you. I will try and get back to you. Little correction: <%#Server.HtmlEncode(Eval("actualContent").ToString()) %>

Comment: @Jams Johnson, I just tried, unfortunately, it does not work. The data in actualContent column is "hello<br />world!", which is in html format, but it shows as "hello<br />world!", the html tag <br /> is not parsed.

Comment: Instead of a div, try using a Literal control, and set the Text property to your HTML content.

Answer (score 0):

Couple of things:

1. Make sure the div is marked with runat="server"
2. on ItemData_Bound, find the div and simply do:

   div.innerHTML=Item.actualContent;

That should do it, I think.

Comment: I added runat="server", actualContent is the column name of that table I am queried from. This part is what I feel puzzled, what should be on the right side of equal sign. But apparently, item.actualContent does not do trick here. what does 'item' stands for? why you use actualContent as a property? Could you please explain your idea in details? Some more code will help a lot. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

hi there is two way for this,

1) set div **InnerHtml** property from .cs file like.

```
div1.InnerHtml = "This data will be bind.";
```

2) if you want fill it from datasource so simply use Eval tag in aspx page like

```
<div ID="div1" runat="server">
<%#Eval("YourColumName")%>
</div>
```